# Split TRY and CATCH EXCEPTION across different .php include files

Tags: php, try-catch

Is there any way in PHP to split `try` and `catch` across two different "include files", putting the `try` in one file and the `catch` in another?

Something like:

```
<?php 
    include('begin_try.php');
      ...
      //some code goes here
      ...
    include('end_try_and_catch_exceptions.php');
?>
```

//filename: begin_try.php:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    try {
?>
```

//filename: end_try_and_catch_exceptions.php:

```
<?php
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo json_encode(array(
          'error' => array(
              'code' => $e->getCode(),
              'message' => $e->getMessage()
          )
      ));
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not syntactically possible to use try-catch like that, but you can use the [`set_exception_handler`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) function to register a function that will catch all exceptions that are not otherwise caught:

```
set_exception_handler(function ($e) {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'error' => array(
            'code' => $e->getCode(),
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        )
    ));
});
```

Comment: Since no one offered better idea I will mark your answer as a correct one.